# Laravel - group data by created_at field and apply pagination

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I need to get previous 10 days activity of a user. In my case i am just getting 10 activity records instead of previous 10 days activity.

***My Code:**

```
$activity   = $this->where('user_id', '=', $userId)->paginate(10);

$activities = collect($activity->items())->groupBy(function($item) {
    return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->format('d-M-Y');
});

$activity->setCollection($activities);

dd($activity->toArray());
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: $activity   = $this->where('user_id', '=', $userId)-> **paginate(10);**  this might be an issue you need to put where condition on $item->created_at by paginate you will only 10 row max.

Answer (score 0):

You are using paginate which restricts the number of results fetched from the DB. If you want to get previous 10 days activity of a user then you can write your query as:

```
$activity = $this->where('user_id', '=', $userId)
                ->where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(10))
                ->get();
```